# Bootstrap Table renewal the result

Tags: javascript, arrays, bootstrap-table

> I am using **Bootstrap Table**

I used this function said in tutorial

```
function (e, value, row, index)
```

which is i only use is `row` and `index`

now when i retrieve the data using this

```
console.log(row);
```

the result is

```
Object {position: "", username: "test@liferay.com", division: "", status: "1", usertype: ""} 2
```

Question is how to retrieve all data in different variable or to array

i tried using this way

```
for (var i in row) {
   console.log(row[i]);
}
```

the result is

```
""
"test@liferay.com"
""
"1"
""
```

> **Update**

I just want to pass all data from `row` to new variable to retrieve them.

i try to output this way `console.log(row[2]);`
result is `undefine`

Comment: What do you need? `row.position` or `row.username` etc...

Comment: i updated may question, is that possible? or i'm missing something? @Michelem

Comment: when i use the `console.log(row);` the result is like an array but when i try to seperate the data using pass the data to array variable, it's always the last data will pass to all array variable and the rest will always overwritten with the last data

Comment: I really can't understand you, please try to put more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `row` is an `object`, so you need to specify the name to get the value :

For example, to get the username, you need :

```
row.username
```

If you really need to convert your object into an array, you can use `map` :

```
var obj = {
    position: "",
    username: "test@liferay.com",
    division: "",
    status: "1",
    usertype: ""
};
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {return obj[key]});
console.log(arr[1]);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0985eLg8/

Answer (score 0):

I did this way thanks @Magicprog.fr

```
var results = JSON.stringify(row);
console.log('results are' + results);
var obj = $.parseJSON(results);
console.log(obj.username);
```

Giving me exact answer